# How to return type as a result of method execution

Tags: c#, types

I have this variable declared:

```
Tuple<bool, string, Type> myVar = new Tuple<bool, string, Type>(false, null, null);
```

And say some classes like - `Account`, `Deposit` and so on

I have a method:

```
public static Tuple<bool, string, Type> myMethod()
{
  return new Tuple<bool, string>(true, accIBANToPayFee, ???);
}
```

And form the method above I want to return the actual type being `Account` or `Deposit` or whatever.

```
myVar = myMethod();
```

Is it possible and how can I do that so I can return the type and extract it from the `myVar` variable?

Comment: Use `GetType()` method on object of your class Account/Deposit.

Comment: I'm wondering if this may be an X-Y problem and perhaps what you are trying to do is not really suited for this?

Comment: @DavidG Sorry but what is `X-Y` problem?

Comment: @Leron Sorry for the jargon! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @DavidG Well, from what it seems if it was an `X-Y` problem I probably wouldn't know.

Comment: What's the end goal?  You can't convert a `Tuple<bool, string, Type>` to a `Tuple<bool, string, Account>` or vice-versa.

Comment: @Leron I guess what I'm asking is: What are you trying to do with this tuple when you get it working? It may be that there is a better way to achieve your end goal if we know what that goal is.

Comment: @GrantWinney not if you are using `null`. It can't infer the type.

Comment: @DStanley The goal is at some point to be able to determine which actual object (representing a financial instrument in this case) is used. The IBAN is the ID of the bank product so if I know if it's Account or Deporist then I'm gonna fetch easily later on. And it seems cleaner to keep only the type until the moment when I'll need the actual obeject.

Comment: @Leron Why not make those object implement a common interface and pass them round instead?

Comment: @DavidG been thinking about this too. A possible solution indeed. However I'm really interested if I can pass the type. In fact `Habib's` answer works for me since I have instance of this class so I can use `GetType()` but what if I hadn't is it still possible to pass the `Type` without creating an instance and invoking `GetType()` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `Type` object from a type, use [`typeof(type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx), eg `typeof(string)`

To get a `Type` object from an instance, use the [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the instance, eg `"string".GetType()`

Use whichever method is appropriate for the third argument of your Tuple

Comment: is there a problem with the answer, why the downvote?